# How to access element by index name by Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have several INPUTs:

```
<input type="text" name="entry[1]" value="aaa" id="firstEntry" />
<input type="text" name="entry[2]" value="bbb" id="secondEntry" />
<input type="text" name="entry[3]" value="ccc" id="thirdEntry" />
```

How to get "2" when I know that element id is "secondEntry"?

```
var name = $("#secondEntry").attr('name'); // name = "entry[2]"
```

But how to get the index 2 ?
I need to know just index (2), not whole name (entry[2]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the name is just a string, and you'd have to do the rest with string manipulation:

```
var name = $("#secondEntry").attr('name'); // name = "entry[2]"
name = name.substring(name.indexOf('[')+1); // name = "2]"

// if you want an integer
name = parseInt(name, 10); // name = 2

// if you want a string representation
name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(']'));  // name = "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always in that format, ie entry[x], then you could use regular expressions;

```
var elename = $("#secondEntry").attr('name');
var i = elename.match("entry\\[([0-9])+\\]");
var ind = i[1];
```

Comment: And if you want it as a number, `var ind = parseInt(i[1])`. But drop "entry" from the regex so it's not fragile (doesn't break on name changes).

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /entry\[(\d{1})\]/;
var index = re.exec(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick using [regular expressions](http://www.google.kz/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+regex).

Answer (score 0):

```
var name  = $("#secondEntry").attr('name');
var index = name.substring( 6, name.length - 1 );
```

Comment: Granted that works for his sample data, but *wow* is it fragile. Breaks if he changes `entry` to `item` at some point, or if there are more than nine, or...

Comment: Of course it only works for "entry", but that is what he is looking at (and the RegExp solutions are not more general either); and regarding your second argument: `'entry[12413525]'.substring( 6, 'entry[12413525]'.length - 1 )` gives me `"12413525"`.

Comment: Re the first item: Yeah, well, I commented on the other one I read too. Re second item: Doh! I just totally misread the length bit.